# Eclipse crashes on importing GooglePlay service library to the project

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, google-play, google-plus

I was about to integrate google plus into my first android project, but once i imported the google_play_service library into my project after performing all the steps mentioned in developer.google.com website my app doesn't launch and the eclipse shutdowns automatically. I have just imported the library and i have not written any code using that library.
Please help me out with this problem.

[image]

Comment: add a screen shot here

Comment: Have a Look This http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: @Naveen I followed the same steps...

Comment: does eclipse showed any error on shutdown ?

Comment: may be something print on console

Comment: I get that error that is shown in the image and later eclipse asks me to close the workbench.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit **eclipse.ini** file

update the default values

**-Xms40m**

**-Xmx512m**

with new values

**-Xms512m**

**-Xmx1024m**

Mac users : try this  http://blog.mynumnum.com/2011/08/how-to-modify-eclipseini-settings-in.html

try this https://www.simplified.guide/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: I am not able to find that file on my mac.

Comment: try this link for mac http://blog.mynumnum.com/2011/08/how-to-modify-eclipseini-settings-in.html